# What is the maximum length of sequence where the sum of 5 consecutive numbers in positive and sum of 8 consecutive numbers is negatve.

Tags: sequences-and-series

As middle number are being repeated and end numbers are not, we can make end numbers as negative so that they are used as little times as possible in the consecutive sequence that we take.
I can think of one such sequence of length as

-21,0,10,10,10,10,0,-21